# error in game of life code in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, pixel-manipulation

I am just a beginner in programming. In the execution of game of life, only initial pattern is showing up. I didn't used grid here. but adjusted the size of rectangle for that. code is not neat. Please kindly make suggestion to get my code work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" >
    </canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
                    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");  
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var width= canvas.width;
        var height = canvas.height;

      function initial(){
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        for(var i=0;i<width;i+=10){
          for(var j=0;j<height;j+=10){
            ctx.fillStyle="white";
            if(Math.random()<0.05){
              ctx.fillStyle="black";
            }
            ctx.fillRect(i,j,9,9);
          }
        }
      }

      function fut(){
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,width, height);
        var data = imageData.data;
        var future = [];
        for(var y=0;y<height;y+=10){
          for(var x=0;x<width;x+=10){
            var dead = data[((width/10*y)+x)*4];
            var numb=0;
            numb = life_around(x,y);
            check_life(numb, dead,future);
          }
        }

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);  
            //ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);  
        for(var i=0;i<width;i+=10){
          for(var j=0;j<height;j+=10){
            var black =future[(width/10*y)+x)*4];
            ctx.fillStyle="white";
            if(black == 0){
              ctx.fillStyle="black";
            }
            ctx.fillRect(i,j,9,9);
          }
        }

        setTimeout(fut,1000);
        function check_life(numb, dead,future){
          if (dead == 0){
            if((numb ==2) || (numb == 3)){
              future.push(0);
              future.push(0);
              future.push(0);
              future.push(255);
            }
          }
          if ((dead!=0)&&(numb == 3)){
            future.push(0);
                        future.push(0);
                        future.push(0);
                        future.push(255);
          } 
          if((dead!=0)&&(numb!=3)){
                        future.push(255);
                        future.push(255);
                        future.push(255);
                        future.push(255);
          } 
        }

        function life_around(x,y){
          for(var i=-10;i<20;i+=10){
            for(var j=-10;j<20;j+=10){
              if((i!=0) || (j!=0)){
                var data_index=((width/10*(y+i))+(x+j))*4;  
                if((data_index >= 0) && (data[data_index]==0)){
                    numb++;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          return numb;
        }
      }

    function run(){
        initial();
        fut();
    }
    //-->
    </script>
    <p>Game of life</p>

    <form action="">
    <input type="button" value="initial" onClick="initial()" >
    <input type="button" value="run" onClick="run()" >
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: pls make the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you please also post the error-message that is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Line 43, added "(":

```
 var black =future[((width/10*y)+x)*4];
```